# Why is Azure Key Vault secure?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

Why or how is Azure Key Vault secure? I need to store key URI and Client Id and Client Secret on the server, so if anyone grants access to the server on which application is hosted, he'll be able to access keys and secrets stored in the Key Vault. Which means it is just as secure to store them on the server, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445378/purpose-of-going-for-an-azure-key-vault-storage?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the Key Vault. Key vault is secure in a sense that nothing gets transmitted over the public internet, all the communications with Key Vault and Azure Resources go through the Azure Backbone, so they are secure by default (well, if you believe Azure is secure).
Also, with Key Vault you can allow for deploying certain certificates without having the ability to look at them (or copy them). Basically, it supports RBAC.

Comment: so storing a config file with some passwords in it won't make sense?

Comment: well, not necessary, but if you App has got access to Key Vault, and somebody hacked your server, he would be able to get the same access if he could reverse your App. It offers no additional protection if you know the password to access it.

Comment: and if i'm using certificate?

Comment: Well, generally speaking, anyone knowing secretID and having certificate can auth to a Key Vault.

Comment: You actually can access Azure Key Vault via the Internet, by using the API. The question is back to the chicken and egg problem brought up in other answers already, e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34170875/471722.

Comment: no its not, the fact that it can be accessed via internet doesnt mean ARM templates do that via internet @Bernd

Comment: @4c74356b41 do you have any reference to Microsoft documentation on how they handle the transmission of secrets/keys over the wire?

Answer (score 9):

This is late for OP, but I hope it can help others to solve the chicken egg problem while using Azure Key Vault.

With the context of running applications on Azure VM, instead of using `client_secret` to authenticate, you can use client certificate authentication as explained in this [documentation: Authenticate with a Certificate instead of a Client Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application#authenticate-with-a-certificate-instead-of-a-client-secret).

[image: Key Vault Client Certificate Authentication Image]

In the picture above:

- Application is authenticating to AAD by proving that it has the private key of the certificate (which is basically stored in [CNG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you are using Windows).
- Application get back the `access_token` and then use it to access the Key Vault.

The developer does not need to know the private key value of the certificate in order for their app to be successfully authenticated. Instead, they only need to know the location of the imported `pfx` (a container for private key and its certificate) in the Certificate Store.

At least on Windows, you as secret administrator can convert the private key and the certificate into `pfx` format which is **password** protected, and then deploy it into the Windows Certificate store. This way no one could know the private key unless they know the **password** of the `pfx` file.

---

The other approach specifics for Azure Compute, is to use [Azure Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview). Using Azure MSI, Azure will automatically assign your resources such as VM with an identity / Service Principal, and you can fire requests at a specific endpoint that are only accessible by your resource to get the `access_token`. But be wary that Azure MSI are still under public preview, so please review the known issues before using it.

[image: Azure Managed Service Identity Image]

The picture above explain how Azure Resource Manager assign a Service Principal identity to your VM.

- When you enable MSI in a VM, Azure will create a service principal in your AAD.
- Azure will then deploy a new MSI VM extension to your VM. This provides an endpoint at http://localhost:50432/oauth2/token to be used to get the `access_token` for the service principal.
- You can then use the `access_token` to access the resources such as Key Vault which authorize the service principal access.

Comment: MSI wasnt a thing when this answer was given. but in reality MSI is not secure at all. anyone who has access to the VM\function\etc can use the same endpoint to obtain the same set of permissions. so arguably its even worse