# How to access Key Vault from a C++ application

Tags: c++, azure-keyvault, microsoft-entra-id

Can you please clarify how to safely access Key Vault from an external application (not deployed on Azure) written in C++?

I've already read several documentation pages on this topic, like this one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide
and it seems that the suggested approach is to create an app registration and a service principal (and give to this identity the appropriate roles) to authenticate the calls to the key vault REST API.

If this is correct, the main doubt now is: where should I store the principal Id and secret to be secure?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

**To access Key Vault from C++ application, check the below:**

Create an **Azure AD application** and grant Azure Key Vault API permission:

[image]

In the Azure Key Vault set the access policy for the application and select the permissions based on your requirement:

[image]

For sample, I generated access token via Postman:

[image]

Now use the access token to access the Key Vault:

```json
GET vaultBaseUrl/secrets/secret-name/secret-version?api-version=7.4
```

[image]

> **If this is correct, the main doubt now is: where should I store the principal Id and secret to be secure?**

You can store the credentials by creating the environment variables:

```cpp
$Env:AZURE_CLIENT_ID="AppID"
$Env:AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="CLientSecret"
$Env:AZURE_TENANT_ID="TenantID"
```

And generate the access token using the application details and for sample to retrieve Key make use of below code snippet:

```cpp
KeyVaultKey key = client.GetKey("key-name");
std::cout << key.Name();
std::cout << key.KeyType.ToString();
```

You can make of REST API calls to access Key Vault refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/#secret-operations-key-vault-only)

**References:**

[azure-security-keyvault-keys: Azure Key Vault key client library for C++ (windows.net)](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/cpp/azure-security-keyvault-keys/4.1.0/index.html#retrieve-a-key)

[c# - Access Azure Key Vault stored secret using application not deployed in Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022041/access-azure-key-vault-stored-secret-using-application-not-deployed-in-azure) by MvdD